# ExtJS tooltip renders wrong with long body

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

First of all, i know i'm using extjs not in the "propper" way, but i also have other features in my site that don't require extjs.

My problem is rather odd. I have an html document like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="extjs">
        //OTHER HTML ELEMENTS HERE
    </div>
</body>
```

However, when i open my extjs application (consists of windows that are used for certain tasks like editing a product), and i scroll (in the browser, not in the extjs elements) and hover over an element with a tooltip, the tooltip is rendered as if the document doesnt have a scrollbar, meaning that the tooltip is rendered all the way to the top of the document, instead of where the cursor is. The same thing goes for drag and drop and pretty much everything related to mouse orientated positions...
I looked around on forums and google and such, but saw noone with a similar problem, so if anyone has an idea how to fix this, that would be very, VERY helpfull!

Here is a screenshot to maybe give a better idea whats going on:

[image: Tooltip rendered wrong]

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is a simple fiddle to demonstrate my problem. since sencha fiddle is made with extjs itself, it autoresolves the problem. Therefor ill only paste the code here so you can test it in your own application.

index.html

```
<div id=extjs style="background-color: red; width: 2000px; height: 3000px;">
    <p>
        content of website is here
    </p>
</div>
```

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            autoShow: true,
            renderTo: Ext.get('extjs'),
            items: {
                xtype: 'form',
                title: 'testform',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'test input',
                    name: 'test',
                    allowBlank: false

                }]
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of you are using and please provide some code.

Comment: i'm using Extjs 5.0.1, and what code do you want, since its not really a code related problem?

Comment: a minimal example application with your problem at https://fiddle.sencha.com would be great to catch the error.

Comment: I created an example in fiddle, however, since fiddle was made with extjs it renders the tooltips and such correctly. In my case, i use extjs just for some functionalities along with the rest of my website (made with php). for those interested, i will post the code of fiddle in the post

Comment: Is it a possibility to run your ExtJS app in an iframe instead of attaching it to a single div in a larger page. ExtJS is designed as a full-page app - if it was in an iframe it probably wouldn't muck up the position calculations.

Comment: well thats the thing, its not an iframe. Its a div right below the body and ends just before the closing tag of the body. Attaching extjs to the body will only allow it to use the initial window size (so without scrolling), and this div allows my windows to use the whole page.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: mozilla firefox. everyone in our company uses mozilla since the website is for administrators only, so to make development easier, we want all users to access the website with mozilla only.

Comment: If tooltip renders good at fiddle.sencha.com then probably something is going wrong in positioning calculations. Maybe your CSS is the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is simple not possible from within extjs. I made a workaround my making my div scrollable and my body not scrollable.